# I have 3 textboxes for input and I need to be able to run a search using any/all of them to sent the user to the correct outside webpage

Tags: html, function, variables

I know just enough programming to know this is possible. It is the how that I am struggling with. I have 3 input text boxes that each will need to be used to run a search. That means I have 3 variables. Does this mean that I need 3 different functions or can I do this in 1 function? How do I get this to work? And is there any easier way to code for multiple variations on words that are inputted for variables b and c? I need to be able to code for ALL of the zip codes, Cities, and Counties within the covered area and linking them to different outside webpages (there are 5 possible webpages the variables will go to) any suggestions on making it easier would be appreciated.

```
            else if (c == "bell county") {
                document.getElementById("County_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup's Meeting page";
                // <a href=""> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
                window.open("", 'newwindow')
            }
            else<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
   h1 {text-align: center;}
   p {text-align: center;}
</style>
    <title>Find your nearest Meeting </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1><b>Finding your nearest meeting</b></h1>
    <p>When leaving your treatment center and going back home, it is importaint to find your nearest AA meeting as soon
        as possible.<br>
        The Area 26 Treatment Committee wants to make this easy for you.
        Please type in your zipcode <b><i>OR</i></b> your city <b><i>OR</i></b> your county in <i><u>one</u></i> of the
        boxes below.<br>
        You will then be directed to the Intergroup meeting webpage that serves that area.
        Here you will be able to locate a meeting and continue your journey in sobrity.<br>
        Remeber, <i>We shall be with you in the Fellowship of the Spirit, and you will surely meet some of us as you
            trudge the
            Road of Happy Destiny.</i>
    </p>
    <br><br>
    <center><label for="Zipcode">Zipcode:</label></center>
    <center><input type="text" id="Zipcode" name="Zipcode"></center>
    <p id="Zipcode_text"></p>
    <br>
    <p><b><i>OR</i></b></p>
    <br>
    <center><label for="City">City:</label></center>
    <center><input type="text" id="City" name="City"></center>
    <p id="City_text"></p>
    <br>
    <p><b><i>OR</i></b></p>
    <br>
    <center><label for="County">County:</label></center>
    <center><input type="text" id="County" name="County"></center>
    <p id="County_text"></p>
    <br><br><br>
    <center><button onclick="myFunction()">Find Meetings Near Me</button></center>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var a = document.getElementById("Zipcode").value;
            var b = document.getElementById("City").value;
            var c = document.getElementById("County").value;
            if (a == "41310") {
                document.getElementById("Zipcode_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup's Meeting page";
                // <a href=""> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
                window.open("", 'newwindow')
            }
            else if (a == "41317") {
                document.getElementById("Zipcode_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup's Meeting page";
                // <a href=""> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
                window.open("", 'newwindow')
            }
            else if (b == "Rousseau") {
                document.getElementById("City_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup's Meeting page";
                // <a href=""> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
                window.open("", 'newwindow')
            }
            else if (b == "rousseau") {
                document.getElementById("City_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup's Meeting page";
                // <a href=""> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
                window.open("", 'newwindow')
            }
            else if (b == "Vancleve") {
                document.getElementById("City_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup's Meeting page";
                // <a href=""> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
                window.open("", 'newwindow')
            }
            else if (b == "vancleve") {
                document.getElementById("City_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup's Meeting page";
                // <a href=""> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
                window.open("", 'newwindow')
            }
            else if (b == "Van Cleve") {
                document.getElementById("City_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup's Meeting page";
                // <a href=""> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
                window.open("", 'newwindow')
            }
 if (c == "Bell county") {
                document.getElementById("County_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup's Meeting page";
                // <a href=""> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
                window.open("", 'newwindow')
            }
            else if (c == "Bell") {
                document.getElementById("County_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup's Meeting page";
                // <a href=""> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
                window.open("", 'newwindow')
            }
            else if (c == "bell") {
                document.getElementById("County_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup's Meeting page";
                // <a href=""> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
                window.open("", 'newwindow')
            }
            else if (c == "Harlan County") {
                document.getElementById("County_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup's Meeting page";
                // <a href=""> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
                window.open("", 'newwindow')
            }
            else if (c == "Harlan county") {
                document.getElementById("County_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup's Meeting page";
                // <a href=""> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
                window.open("", 'newwindow')
            }
            else if (c == "Harlan") {
                document.getElementById("County_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup's Meeting page";
                // <a href=""> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
                window.open("", 'newwindow')
            }
            else if (c == "harlan") {
                document.getElementById("County_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup's Meeting page";
                // <a href=""> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
                window.open("", 'newwindow')
            }
        else {
                document.getElementById("County_text").innerHTML = "I'm sorry but we have not found a local Intergroup Meeting Page that has meetings in that area. Please go to the Area 26 meeting page for a list of meetings in Kentucky, Southern Indiana and Ohio.";
                // <a href=""> Area 26 Find A Meeting Page</a>;
                window.open("", 'newwindow')
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I enter any of the coded answers into the text boxes and hit the button, nothing happens. When I remove variables b and c and just run on variable a, it works. SO I am doing something wrong with coding for variables b and c.

I removed the outside webpage addresses because Stack Overflow said my question was spam